# Shap application with your own model, using as weights a transformer model

Tags: python, nlp, transformer-model, shap

I would like to create one shap using my model in .pt format. But I have always the same error. Below I put a little bit of one script:

```
config = XLMRobertaConfig.from_pretrained("xlm-roberta-base")
model = XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification(config)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model_08.pt", map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
model.eval()
```

The error is this:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-efc818b47f22> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 
      7 # Carica i pesi del modello
----> 8 model.load_state_dict(torch.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/Classificazione_tweet/modelli_fatti/model_08/model_08.pt", map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
      9 
     10 # Imposta il modello in modalità valutazione

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   2039 
   2040         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
-> 2041             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
   2042                                self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   2043         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification:
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "roberta.embeddings.position_ids".
```